# How can I mock other class instances, phpunit?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I have the code below. How can I unit-test the run function without executing the **$video->run();**

Actually, how can I mock the ***$video->run();*** call in the code below? Is it even possible?

```
class Runner
{
    ...

    public function run()
    {
        $task = $this->getTask();

        switch ( $task->getType() ) {
            case Task::TYPE_VIDEO:
                $video = new Video( $task );
                $video->run();
                return 1;
                break;

            default:
                echo "Not implemented task runner";
                return 9;
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Mockery](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/index.html) to mock the $video->run() method call. First you create a mock for the Video class by using an "instance mock" like this:

```
$videoMock = Mockery::mock('overload:MyNamespace\Video');
```

This will "intercept" when a new instance of the Video class is created and the `$videoMock` will be used instead. When the '$videoMock' is created you just need to add an expectation declaration for the given method:

```
$videoMock->shouldReceive('run')->once();
```

The [Mockery quick reference](https://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/getting_started/quick_reference.html) might give some good information about how to use the framework.

Comment: Thanks! Looks interesting. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

the easy way would be to create a new method in the class.

Than you have to mock getVideo and return a mocked object of Video than you can mock the method run, in the mocked object of Video too.

Its not the best way, but it would be possible.

```
public function run()
{
    $task = $this->getTask();

    switch ($task->getType()) {
        case Task::TYPE_VIDEO:
            $this->getVideo($task)->run();
            return 1;
            break;

        default:
            echo "Not implemented task runner";
            return 9;
            break;
    }
}

protected function getVideo($task)
{
    return new Video($task);
}
```